# #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-error-1054

Below is the code that keeps giving me alias error:

```
SELECT name,
       semester
FROM   (SELECT name,
               semester,
               (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM   instructors AS i
                       JOIN teaches
                         ON i.id = teaches.instructor_id
                       JOIN schedules
                         ON teaches.schedule_id = schedules.id
                       JOIN sections AS s
                         ON schedules.section_id = s.id
                WHERE  i.name = instructors.name
                       AND hour_start > 10
                       AND ( hour_end < 17
                              OR ( hour_end = 17
                                   AND min_end <> 0 ) )
                       AND s.semester = sections.semester)  AS c1,
               (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM   instructors AS i2
                       JOIN teaches
                         ON i2.id = teaches.instructor_id
                       JOIN schedules
                         ON teaches.schedule_id = schedules.id
                       JOIN sections AS s2
                         ON schedules.section_id = s2.id
                WHERE  i2.name = instructors.name
                       AND s2.semester = sections.semester) AS c2
        FROM   instructors
               JOIN teaches
                 ON instructors.id = teaches.instructor_id
               JOIN schedules
                 ON teaches.schedule_id = schedules.id
               JOIN sections
                 ON schedules.section_id = sections.id
        WHERE  c1 = c2)
GROUP  BY name,
          semester
ORDER  BY name,
          semester;
```

Answer (score 2):

Give an alias to your subquery,all your inner queries have aliases like c1,c2 but your first level subquery doesn't have an alias

```
SELECT t.name,
       t.semester
FROM   ( ........) t
GROUP  BY t.name,
          t.semester
ORDER  BY t.name,
          t.semester;
```